# cvs update - cannot open temp file for writing no such file or directory

Tags: java, windows, cvs, tortoisecvs, cvsnt

Disclaimer: This isn't my repo, I'm trying to help a developer access theirs.

When checking out code (windows server 2003, tortoiseCVS 1.12.5), CVS displays many errors:

```
cvs udpate: cannot open temp file _new_r_cl_elementBeanInternalHome_12345b.class for writing
```

Eventually failing and aborting on the error:

```
cvs [update aborted]: cannot make directory path/path/path/PATH/Path/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/FOO/com/ams/BAR/entityBean/websphere_deploy/DB2UDBOS123_V0_1 no such file or directory.
```

There's nothing handy on Google about this or on stack overflow so far.

We do have a web browser on the cvs server and I can see the paths match and there are files there.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you please check if you have adequate persmissions on folder where you are checking out.

Comment: Server: have permissions to entire cvsroot (tried two users), PC: checking out to desktop as a test, folder owned by user. This error occurs for both users I tried, which makes me think it is something it doesn't like about the file names or path it's trying to create?

Comment: Is that the actual directory path it says or have you obfuscated it?

Comment: It's not the actual path, but the elements I replaced were numerical with no special chars. (A-Z0-9)

Comment: The reason I asked is that Windows will give a 'No such file or directory' error if a path longer that a certain number of characters (256 I think). What is the length of your actual path?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wasn't able to check out to drive D: in windows but was able to checkout to drive c:
I believe that the problem is with the disk drive or filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Standard Windows API has 260-character limit for paths to any files. If the whole path to the file exceeds that limit you won't be able to save that file to in system.

Try to checkout repository as close the root of the disk as possible. If the file paths in you repo exceeds the limit, then try to checkout only fragment of the tree of your repository.

If you use the NTFS file system and the win32 API you can have as long as 32k characters path length. You may change your CVS client to other implementation, for example the Netbeans plugin for CVS is able to handle long paths, but probably you won't be able to work with it anyway.